# must I use root in production

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, deployment

This is strange in my database.yml I have the following

```
  production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: ajhezaty_production
  pool: 5
  user: myname
  password: "mygreatpassword"
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
  host: mysql.asdf.com
  timeout: 500
```

when I run rails server locally in production mode

```
  11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:53:in `connect': Access denied for user 'root'@'c-71- (using password: YES) (Mysql2::Error)
```

why did it use root! I have different username in database.yml

when I accessed client.rb and hardcoded  the usernae it works !

Comment: tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675489/mysql2error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-no

Comment: I saw it. it didnt help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try username instead of user ;-)

Comment: superhero! it works :) thanks